# How can I retrieve the e-mail I was writing on my iPad?

Tags: backup, ios, data-recovery, mobile-mail

On my iPad, I was writing an e-mail.

I switched to Mail, and my e-mail in progress had the text “Chargement en cours…” (“Loading”) in grey instead of my text. I waited. To no avail.

I have a backup of my iPad.

**How can I retrieve the e-mail in progress ?**

At worst, I might rely on the snapshot of the screen of the app Mail.

**How can I find the snapshot of the screen of the app Mail ?**

I have iOS 5.

Comment: Have you looked in the drafts for the email account

Comment: @markhunte - Yes, I have looked in the Drafts. To no avail. :-(